# Eclipse want to know jboss connectivity with 7.1.0 version

Tags: eclipse, jboss

Im using eclipse 3.1.0 version of eclipse, and want to know the how to connect jboss 7.1.0, as my eclipse shows server list upto only jboss 5 version. any help?

Answer (score 0):

You should install the [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools). They add the more recent versions of the JBoss server.

And probably you will have to update your IDE as well. I doubt that there is a current version of the JBoss Tools for eclipse 3.1.x